# How delete a document if the current date > document date

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following schema:

```
Schema = {(
   name: String,
   age: Number,
   email: String,
   date: {
     type: Date
   }
)};
```

And i am inserting data in my db dinamically throw a form and a post route. After that, i am pulling this data and showing in the html using ejs view engine.

The problem is that i want delete documents who have the date field less than the current date.

I was trying to use [TTL](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/#expire-documents-at-a-certain-clock-time), but i don't know exactly how implement, should i use in the schema, or before save the data, in a new entry?

For example, in my post route i have the following code:

```
var new = new Schema({
   name: req.body.name,
   age: req.body.age,
   email: req.body.email,
   date: {
     type: req.body.date
   }
});

new.save...... 
.... etc
```

I want delete this document 24 hours after the req.body.date, and no 24 after created...

I'm little confuse, any help is very welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with a [TTL collection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/#expire-documents-after-a-certain-number-of-seconds).

You could set the `expireAfterSeconds` to 86400 and set the date element to the current date and it should expire after a full day.

The way this would be implemented is that while connected to the server you would issue this command:

```
db.collection.ensureIndex( { "date.type": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 86400 } )
```

I don't know how your application sends what data it sends to MongoDB, but you'll want to make sure that it is sending a timestamp corresponding to the midnight before the current time.

For example if it is 1/29/2015 at 2:07:33 PM when the form is sent, the timestamp sent to MongoDB should be 1/29/2015 12:00:00 AM. With the index set above, MongoDB will remove the document at 1/30/2015 at 12:00:00 AM.

Comment: sorry.. document haha

Comment: i can do that even if i am using a form to insert the date value??

Comment: Yes, I believe if you are only looking at that field as a date type then you can always set the `date` field to midnight of the current date. Then with the `expireAfterSeconds` set to the number of seconds in a day, it should remove the document at midnight the next day.

Comment: no problem @NoOutlet.. again, i'm sorry, i was thinking that you give up and i am stuck haha :P